# SpecFlow + VSTS/TFS 2015

Tags: azure-devops, specflow, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

Using the new build system in TFS2015/VSTS, my SpecFlow tests aren't getting picked up. Within the same project, classes and methods decorated with `[TestClass]` and `[TestMethod]`, respectively, are picked up and tested by TFS. What are the basic requirements for TFS2015/VSTS to run a SpecFlow 2.0 test?

EDIT: Adding `packages.config` contents. As you can see, I have `SpecRun` installed, and from within Visual Studio, I'm able to run SpecFlow tests as I'd expect (i.e. they all appear in Test Explorer)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SpecFlow" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SpecRun.Runner" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SpecRun.SpecFlow" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: I assume you have referenced the SpecRun.Runner assembly in your project?

Comment: Have you set the path to the custom teat runners: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511081/how-to-run-xunit-in-visualstudioonline-build/34879593#34879593

Comment: Can you also provide your SRProfile?

Comment: @DaveShaw, in my case, the answer was to set the custom test runners path. If you want to add that as an answer, I can mark it as such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit you VS Test Task and set the Path to Custom Test Adapters` to where in Source Control your "packages" folder lives.

For example:

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Already looked at this answer? [Built tests are not added to the Visual Studio Test Explorer window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573482/built-tests-are-not-added-to-the-visual-studio-test-explorer-window/34556332#34556332)

1. Close all Visual Studio instances
2. Go to %TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\
3. Delete all the folders in here
4. Try again

This helped me out this morning (VS2017, SpecFlow Version:2.1.0.0, SpecFlow+ Excel Version:1.4.2.0).