# SpecFlow Build TFS 2015

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015, specflow

I'm unable to get my SpecFlow Tests to run from a build in TFS 2015. This appears to be similar to the issue mentioned in

SpecFlow + VSTS/TFS 2015
[SpecFlow + VSTS/TFS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184417/specflow-vsts-tfs-2015)

The Answer given here did not solve my problem.  I added $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages
To my Path to Custom Test Adaptors and got an error:

Error: The path 'D:\vNextBuildAgent\1_work\b5a9c222\Platform\packages' specified in the 'TestAdapterPath' is invalid. Error: The custom test adapter search path provided was not found, provide a valid path and try again.
VSTest Test Run failed with exit code: 1

Is (Build.SourcesDirectory) a pre-defined variable, a variable I need to set in my build definition, or something else?  Is there another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Build.SourcesDirectory` is a [predefined variable](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables), which is the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded.

In the link you provide, `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages` is an example, you need to specify where in Source Control your "packages" folder lives.

> **Path to Custom Test Adaptors** is the path to any custom or third-party test adapters for the framework for which the tests are
>   written.
>
> - Supports a wide range of test frameworks such as NUnit, xUnit, Mocha,    and Jasmine
> - Automatically searches subfolders.
> - Automatically scans any **packages** folder and installs and uses any    NuGet packages containing test adapters without prompting.
> - Example: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Fabrikam\packages

Comment: If I didn't have access to my build machine, and couldn't see my packages folder, nuget packages, or customer test controller in TFS Source Control, is there a way I could determine what the correct path is?

Comment: If there is a packages folder in the sources directory, it is automatically searched for testadapters. Hence, any testadapter downloaded as a Nuget package will be used without any input. Otherwise, you need to indicate the path for the test adaptor.

Comment: Without access to brows the build server's file system, you can add temporary debug PowerShell script steps into your build definition with filtered Get-ChildItem calls to determine the presence of your packages..